# Yii2 Active Record to raw sql

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-active-records

I would like to convert the active record query of yii2 to raw SQL equivalent to check if the query is working correctly or not.

It is easy to convert the Eloquent ORM of laravel to raw SQL using `toSql()` method

> https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql

Is there any way to achieve this result in yii2, as I can only find the solutions from raw SQL to active record implementation.

If the question is still not clear will add the example for further explaination.

Comment: [What have you researched before asking that question?](https://www.google.com/search?q=yii2+active+record+get+raw+sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use either the property [sql](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#$sql-detail) or the method [rawSql()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#$rawSql-detail) of the `query->command`, for example:

```php
$querySql = Model::find()->where(...)->createCommand()->sql;
$querySql = Model::find()->where(...)->createCommand()->getRawSql();

// Or, if you want to use the query somewhere else
$query = Model::find()->where(...);
...
$sql = $query->createCommand()->sql;
```

If you are just debugging, it is probably easier to see the query on the debug toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, I could not find any better resource than this answer.